# Getting root node of the breadcrumb using mvcsitemap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, sitemap, mvcsitemapprovider

I have a sitemap node and the format is as follows:

```
<mvcSitemapenode title="A"/>
```

Is it possible to get the parent node using `Mvcsitemap()` in the cshtml file?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the parent node like this:

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap().Provider.CurrentNode.ParentNode
```

The provider is inherits from the abstract [SiteMapProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sitemapprovider.aspx) class